# Ruby on Rails two factor authentication with Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, two-factor-authentication

I would like to setup two factor authentication with devise using Ruby on Rails 5. I've been using multiple gems with no luck what so ever. I was hoping if anyone out there could help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Hey! What's your specific problem? I can certainly try to help but I need a bit more to go on than this :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use a certain gem on my project to enable two factor authentication when I try logging into an account. I came across this gem that looks promising http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-rails-app-with-devise or heck even this one if it works with rails 5 as it claims to https://github.com/CyberDeck/devise-fido-u2f

Comment: Ok, and is that gem not working for you for some reason? Can you share the error message and what you've tried?

Comment: Thats the thing, I go through the steps on installing the gem and then I'm stuck where to go next as I haven't found a reasonable walkthrough to follow

Comment: Both of those gems are for 2FA with a hardware token like a Yubikey, is that the sort of thing you want to build? Or were you looking for TOTP?

Comment: I can share my github if that gives you a better understanding https://github.com/callags/Karaz-Ankor

Comment: yeah I would like to use a yubikey

Comment: Ok, looks like `yubikey_database_authenticatable` is probably unmaintained and might not work with Rails 5. Have you followed the instructions in the Readme for `devise-fido-u2f`?

Comment: I haven't even tried the instructions of the devise-fido-u2f

Comment: That's probably where I'd start then!

Comment: fair enough lol

Comment: I installed the devise-fido-u2f gem. Part of the documentation mentioned that this gem wont work unless the rails app supports ssl/https. Any ideas how to enable https in development? I have been looking at letsencrypt as a possibility, but so far I found how to do it in a production server.

Comment: I've not enabled SSL in dev for myself, but the [results here look promising](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+development+ssl)

Comment: So far nothing has worked for me. Edit: It didn't work because of user error *facepalm*

Comment: So i bought a yubikey and managed to get the U2F authentication to work perfectly. Now my problem is when I try to create new user at the sign_up page under normal devise it will not save when I logout of my app. Before I added the fido_usf gem I did create a user as the "admin" account. When I login in the admin account I'm greeted with the "authenticate the key" where I press the button on my yubikey and I'm good to go. If I try to signup another user it will never save them the second I logout. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what's going on there. I'd recommend opening a new question about that specific issue and share the code you're using and any other details you can.

Comment: yeah I have been very vague in the last few comments here. I did create another question if you want to see what I'm working with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603608/devise-cant-save-user